# Unwanted thin border with border-bottom

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome

on Android devices' Chrome browser and also when I view my website in Chrome Developer Tools to simulate different devices, there is a thin border below my css border-bottom (the very thin red line below the big white bottom-border-line in the middle red box):

[a red thin line below the big white bottom-border-line in the middle red box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdjjG.jpg)

Where did it come from? How can I remove it? In Firefox or on Desktop normal view in Chrome this thin line is not visibile. Here is my HTML:

```
<header>
<nav>
<a href='#'>test</a>
<a href='#' class='selected'>test</a>
<a href='#'>test</a>
</nav>
</header>
```

And my CSS:

```
header {
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

header nav {
    display: flex;
}

header nav a {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 5px solid blue;
    border-bottom: none;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}

header nav a.selected {
    background-color: red;
    border-bottom: 5px solid white;
}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: can you post a working code snippet of your problem?

Comment: It seems like that thin line is reflecting anchor's background-color. http://i.imgur.com/p2Uh0wb.png But why ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `header nav a { background-clip: padding-box; }` to remove it.

Comment: Thanks, that removes the line below the border, but also adds thin lines to the side of the box... And if the background has a color, this color shines forth.